# Can I make same class for different uses and pass a string along with it for different JsonProperty

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, api, backend

I want to have a class that can have different JsonProperty according to what I want to set.
Example:

```
public class common {
@JsonProperty("what I want")
private String s;
}

public class first {
@JsonProperty("first")
private List<Common> firstCommonList;
}

public class second {
@JsonProperty("second")
private List<Common> secondCommonList;
}
```

How can I have the `JsonProperty` for the common class as let's say "firstCommon" using the class `first` and "secondCommon" using the class `second`? Is there any way to do this or do I have to make separate classes for them and not just a common one?

Please help if you know. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is not possible. Annotations require compile time constants and you are asking for it to be changed according to the runtime parent class type. I would go with two different classes unless the common attributes are really in huge number that justify having a common class.

Comment: Okay. Yes actually this common class is used almost 10 times and only the property name needs to change every time. So if you find any way let me know

Comment: But if it is in fact a common thing why do you want to rename the property? Then it is not a common thing after all.